# Why is my line not drawing over time?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to have a line draw to the canvas over a certain amount of time(ten seconds to be exact).  I'm able to see that the script is counting to a certain time and then stopping, but I'm not seeing the line being drawn.  Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  canvas = document.getElementById("test");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var count = 0;
  var start_x = 0;
  var start_y = 100;
  var end_x = 50;
  var end_y = 100;

  var counter = setInterval(countNumbers, 1000);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(start_x, start_y);
  console.log("Start");
  
  function countNumbers(){
    count += 1;
    ctx.lineTo((start_x + count), start_y);
    console.log(count);
    if((start_x == end_x) || (count == 10)){
      clearInterval(counter);
      console.log("End");
    }
  }
  
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
  ctx.stroke();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="test"></canvas>
```

Comment: @Mr.PolywhirlWhat is that just another way to get the context of the canvas?

Comment: Yeah, since you are using jQuery, why not? ;-)

Comment: Force of habit.  I'm used to doing it the traditional way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move `stroke` inside the `Interval`. Because in your case `stroke` are called immediately without `lineTo` data. And after that `lineTo` are called in interval function and cannot be rendered without `stroke`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  canvas = document.getElementById("test");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var count = 0;
  var start_x = 0;
  var start_y = 100;
  var end_x = 50;
  var end_y = 100;

  var counter = setInterval(countNumbers, 1000);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(start_x, start_y);
  console.log("Start");

  function countNumbers(){
    count += 1;
    ctx.lineTo((start_x + count), start_y);
    console.log(count);
    if((start_x == end_x) || (count == 10)){
      clearInterval(counter);
      console.log("End");

      ctx.lineWidth = 5; // <----- move here
      ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }



})
```

Also ensure that you are not drawing **white** lines on **white** background

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  canvas = document.getElementById("test");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var count = 0;
  var start_x = 0;
  var start_y = 100;
  var end_x = 50;
  var end_y = 100;

  var counter = setInterval(countNumbers, 1000);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(start_x, start_y);
  console.log("Start");      
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";      
  
  function countNumbers(){
    count += 1;
    ctx.lineTo((start_x + count), start_y);
                    
  ctx.stroke();
    console.log(count);
    if((start_x == end_x) || (count == 10)){
      clearInterval(counter);
      console.log("End");        
  ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="test"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hint: some description of what you've changed would improve this answer tenfold.

Comment: This just copied @phts answer.

Comment: @Robert, please check the answer and posted time before comment like this.

Answer (score 0):

I would count down for the step. This will allow you to figure out the step.

I modified your code to allow you to pass parameters into the interval function to minimize global scope variables. Since I passed a reference of the interval into itself, you no longer need to have global variables.

I created two function, the first will create a path and then stroke it. The second one will stroke a sub-line after each tick of the interval. I added a simple check for even-odd to swap between colors.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var canvas  = $('canvas#test')[0];
  var ctx     = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var count   = 10;
  var start_x = 50,               start_y = 50;
  var end_x   = 250,              end_y   = 150;
  var delta_x = end_x - start_x,  delta_y = end_y - start_y;
  var step_x  = delta_x / count,  step_y  = delta_y / count;

  canvas.width  = 300;
  canvas.height = 200;
  
  // Fill canvas with solid black.
  ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fill();
  
  // Kick off the line stroke timer. No more global variables!
  var counter = setInterval(function(opts) {
    // Pass a reference to the timer into the interval.
    strokeLineTimerLive(counter, opts);
  }, 500, {
    ctx : ctx,
    n   : count,
    x1  : start_x,
    y1  : start_y,
    x2  : end_x,
    y2  : end_y,
    dx  : step_x,
    dy  : step_y,
  });
  
  // After the interval has ended, the path is finally stroked. 
  function strokeLineTimer(timer, opts) {
    if (!opts.init) {
      console.log("Start");
      opts.ctx.beginPath();
      opts.ctx.moveTo(opts.x1, opts.y1);
      opts.ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      opts.ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
      opts.init = true;
    }
    opts.n -= 1;
    opts.ctx.lineTo((opts.x1 += opts.dx), (opts.y1 += opts.dy));
    console.log(opts.n);
    if ((opts.x1 == opts.x2) || (opts.n == 0)){
      clearInterval(timer);
      opts.ctx.stroke();
      console.log("End");
    }
  }
  
  // After each tick of the interval, a line is stroked.
  function strokeLineTimerLive(timer, opts) {
    if (!opts.init) {
      console.log("Start");
      opts.ctx.beginPath();
      opts.ctx.moveTo(opts.x1, opts.y1);
      opts.ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      opts.init = true;
    }
    opts.n -= 1;
    opts.ctx.strokeStyle = opts.n % 2 == 0 ? 'white' : 'red';
    opts.ctx.lineTo((opts.x1 += opts.dx), (opts.y1 += opts.dy));
    opts.ctx.stroke();
    console.log(opts.n);
    if ((opts.x1 == opts.x2) || (opts.n == 0)){
      clearInterval(timer);
      console.log("End");
    } else {
      opts.ctx.beginPath();
      opts.ctx.moveTo(opts.x1, opts.y1);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="test"></canvas>
```

Comment: This doesn't really do what I want though.  This, for some reason, waits a few seconds, then draws the entire line at once.  That's not my goal.

Comment: @Robert: Does my `strokeLineTimerLive()` function work as you expect it to work?

Comment: Yeah, that's the general idea of what I was trying to accomplish.